# Create variables from list PYTHON

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm trying to iterate over a list and create different variables that I can use outside of the loop, depending on the value of the variable, but the code I came up with is very long and over several lines.

My first try was with if/else statements over 9 lines (too long), then I tried creating a `for` loop, but then it ended up being even longer (3 variables with 3 possible values = 27 possible combinations), so I've not added this to the question. I also thought I could create a dictionary with the variables as keys (`rdict = {rate1 : value1, rate2 : value2, rate3 : value3,}`), and then re-assign the keys according to the values of the list but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Is there any way I can re-write this so that it's more compact?

```py
if (rates[0] <= 999):
    rate1 = rates[0]
elif (rates[0] <= 999999):
    rate1 = rates[0] / 1000
elif (rates[0] > 999999):
    rate1 = rates[0] / 1000000

if (rates[1] <= 999):
    rate2 = rates[1]
elif (rates[1] <= 999999):
    rate2 = rates[1] / 1000
elif (rates[1] > 999999):
    rate2 = rates[1] / 1000000

if (rates[2] <= 999):
    rate3 = rates[2]
elif (rates[2] <= 999999):
    rate3 = rates[2] / 1000
elif (rates[2] > 999999):
    rate3 = rates[2] / 1000000

print("Rate1 : \t" + str(rate1) + " \n Rate2 : \t" + str(rate2) + " \n Rate3 : \t" + str(rate3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make the observation that the 3 fragments (for each `rates` item) are equivalent, so they can be refactored into a function:

```py
if (rates[0] <= 999):
    rate1 = rates[0]
elif (rates[0] <= 999999):
    rate1 = rates[0] / 1000
elif (rates[0] > 999999):
    rate1 = rates[0] / 1000000
```

becomes

```py
def map_rate(rate):
    if rate <= 999:
        return rate
    elif rate <= 999999:
        return rate / 1000
    else:
        return rate / 1000000
```

and you could now call it like

```py
rate1 = map_rate(rates[0])
rate2 = map_rate(rates[1])
rate3 = map_rate(rates[2])
```

which is nice already. However, there's no real reason to use free variables (`rate1`, etc.); instead you can use a list comprehension to map every value in `rates` to a new list:

```py
mapped_rates = [map_rate(rate) for rate in rates]
```

Then, it's quite easy to print all mapped rates, no matter how many there are. I'm using the `enumerate()` function to get the index of the rate too.

```py
for i, rate in enumerate(mapped_rates, 1):
    print("Rate{}:\t{}".format(i, rate))
```

All in all, this becomes (sans the declaration of `map_rate()` from above):

```py
rates = [3524, 4509353, 36333]
mapped_rates = [map_rate(rate) for rate in rates]
for i, rate in enumerate(mapped_rates, 1):
    print("Rate{}:\t{}".format(i, rate))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extract your logic into a function:

```py
def reformat(n: int):
    while n > 1000:
        n = n / 1000
    return str(n)

print(
    "Rate1 : \t" + reformat(rates[0]) +
    " \n Rate2 : \t" + reformat(rates[1]) +
    " \n Rate3 : \t" + reformat(rates[2])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function.

```
def convert_rate(rate):
    if rate <= 999:
        return rate
    elif rate <= 999999:
        return  rate / 1000
    elif rate > 999999:
        return rate / 1000000


rates = [0, 1000, 1000000]
rate1 = convert_rate(rates[0])
rate2 = convert_rate(rates[1])
rate3 = convert_rate(rates[2])

print("Rate1 : \t" + str(rate1) + "\nRate2 : \t" + str(rate2) + "\nRate3 : \t" + str(rate3))
```